# ASP Core violates the constraint of type parameter 'TRole' for String

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use [openiddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) and EF 7 in my ASP Core RC2 site.  When I try to create a migration using `dotnet ef migrations add <name>` I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[1], 'System.String', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`3[TUser,TRole,TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TRole'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[1], 'System.String', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TRole'.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr* pInst, Int32 numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)
```

In my Startup.cs I have the following:

```
        services.AddIdentity<MyUser, string>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddOpenIddict();
```

My User and context are defined like this:

```
         public class MyUser : IdentityUser
         {
         }
         public class MyContext : OpenIddictContext<MyUser>
         {
         }
```

I think the error has something to do with the fact that I said to use string `string` for TRole.  Is this not allowed?  What types are supported for TRole?

Answer (score 4):

> I think the error has something to do with the fact that I said to use string string for TRole. Is this not allowed? What types are supported for TRole?

Nope, it's not. When using the default Entity Framework stores for ASP.NET Core Identity, your role entity must inherit from [`IdentityRole`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityRole.cs).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) :

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction) where TUser : class where TRole : class
```

`TRole` must be reference type so instead of `string` use `IdentityRole` in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` namespace.

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddOpenIddict();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have customized role as **ApplicationRole** and i used like below

```
        services.AddIdentity<LD.Domain.Repositories.ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DomainDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

has worked